# JSON.Parse in JS is returning undefined - (Node.js app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing

I created a function to convert JSON in CSV. However JSON.parse is returning undefined. Please can someone help.

```
function JSONtoCSVConverter(JSONDataPath, showLabels) {
  var JSONData = fs.readFile(JSONDataPath, "utf-8", (err, fileContent) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(fileContent);
      JSON.parse(fileContent.toString().trim());
    }
  });

  console.log(JSONData);

  if (showLabels) {
    console.log(JSONData.slice(1, JSONData.length));
    var rowsOfDataArray = Object.keys(JSONData[0]);
    var rowsOfData = rowsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
  }

  JSONData.forEach((object) => {
    var cellsOfDataArray = Object.values(object);
    cellsOfData = cellsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
  });

  var csv = rowsOfData + "\n" + cellsOfData;
  return csv;
}
```

However, the error I have received is:

`undefined TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')     at JSONtoCSVConverter (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\routes\reports.js:45:26)     at C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\routes\reports.js:26:7     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)     at next (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)     at C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)     at next (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)     at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\harsh\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Web Development\contactStoreApp\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)`

Comment: `readFile` is `async` so you won't be immediately able to log the result of the read like that which is why it's `undefined`.

Comment: And just to be clear, when @Andy says it's `async` they don't mean that it's an `async` function (see my answer below). It's async in the fact that's its doing work asynchronously.

Comment: [A promise version of `readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) was added in version 10. Which may help.

Comment: I think the mistake is, in your readFile's callback function you have parsed the data. But you have not returned the data. That will cause for getting undefined. return the parsed data. Or else the issues happen because of async, use the readFileSync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse` returns undefined or `fs.readFile` returns `undefined`? `fs.readFile` is [not supposed to return anything](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback)

If you want to properly use the result of `fs.readFile`, you must put the rest of the code in the callback like so:

```js
function JSONtoCSVConverter(JSONDataPath, showLabels) {
    fs.readFile(JSONDataPath, "utf-8", (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(fileContent);
            var JSONData = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString().trim());
            console.log(JSONData);

            if (showLabels) {
                console.log(JSONData.slice(1, JSONData.length));
                var rowsOfDataArray = Object.keys(JSONData[0]);
                var rowsOfData = rowsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
            }

            JSONData.forEach((object) => {
                var cellsOfDataArray = Object.values(object);
                cellsOfData = cellsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
            });

            var csv = rowsOfData + "\n" + cellsOfData;
            console.log(csv)
        }
    });
}
```

You might have noticed, this is quite messy - this sort of pattern has been dubbed [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com), and is an older-style of programming in JavaScript when using non-blocking APIs. You will also have noticed that I'm not `return`ing the variable `csv` - to do that, you must pass a callback function to `JSONtoCSVConverter` as a third parameter.

Here is an example of doing that (it is called the *callback pattern*).

```js
function JSONtoCSVConverter(JSONDataPath, cb) {
    fs.readFile(JSONDataPath, "utf-8", (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
            cb(err, undefined);
        } else {
            var JSONData = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString().trim());
            cb(null, JSONData);
        }
    });
}

// use the function like this:
JSONtoCSVConverter('./file.json', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);  
  } else {
    console.log('here is JSON data:')
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

But, there is a much better solution.

A better solution involves using promises. Recent version of NodeJS have Promise-based APIs (ex. see [fs.promises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options) that allow you to use them like so:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

async function JSONtoCSVConverter(JSONDataPath, showLabels) {
    var fileContent = await fs.promises.readFile(JSONDataPath, "utf-8")
    console.log(fileContent);
    var JSONData = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString().trim());
    console.log(JSONData);

    if (showLabels) {
        console.log(JSONData.slice(1, JSONData.length));
        var rowsOfDataArray = Object.keys(JSONData[0]);
        var rowsOfData = rowsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
    }

    JSONData.forEach((object) => {
        var cellsOfDataArray = Object.values(object);
        cellsOfData = cellsOfDataArray.join(",") + "\n";
    });

    var csv = rowsOfData + "\n" + cellsOfData;
    return csv;
}
```